# How can I select several spans using selenium

Tags: selenium

In [here](http://www.spareroom.co.uk/flatshare/?search_id=234909059&) I have a lot of results.  "Free to Contact", how can I select all of it to send a message?

Answer (score 0):

in selenium you can select all the elements with css selector span.listing_contactable then you will need to switch to the new opened tab and do other actions.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using "FindElementsBy" function to find all the "Free to Contact" and then clicking on them one by one and then sending the message.

```
List<WebElement> allfreetoContact = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Free to Contact']"));
```

This will store all the 'Free to Contact' elements. Now you can iterate through each of the element and send the message.